# Masks on vaadin7 TextField?

Tags: java, frameworks, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm looking for a solution for my problem with TextField. I need add masks on my textfields but I don't know how do this....I did try use MaskedTextField addon but I think that does not work on vaadin7.

I need masks: uppercase text, phone numbers, postal code, date and money values.

Any idea ?

thanks

Comment: it would be nice if you just mark all your other vaadin questions which are answered so far! Thats the sense of stackoverflow otherwise people won't start answering your questions anymore!

Comment: @nexus I mark with green V my friend...all answeres that help me !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by Masks, but you could just add your own [`Validator`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Validator.html) implementation to the field. 
If you need client side validation and even want to prevent invalid input, the [CSValidation add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/csvalidation) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a [Converter](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/converter/Converter.html). More information [here](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/datamodel.properties.html) under 9.2.3.